# How to return multiple types of objects to python from one C++ function?

Tags: python, c++, boost, iterator, containers

In my application I have to have an interface between a C++ class representing a data table and python, which needs to iterate over said table. The problem appears because the table records which of it's rows and columns are selected and operates on them accordingly; so sometimes the object is a table with only one column selected and the iterator should iterate over that columns, and sometimes it has more than one column selected and should iterate over the columns themselves.  Essentially the type of the iterator needs to change based on the internal state of the table.

If this were pure C++ I would simply change it so that the indexing operator of the table returns a column rather than the table with that column selected; however this will not work because of python's slice operator, which could select zero or more columns, so the problem would be moved rather than solved--this is why it doesn't return the individual columns currently.

It seems like this should be easy to do because python is a dynamic language, so I just have to return the PyObject form of the iterator.  However I can't figure out how to use the wrapper declared with boost::python to convert the C++ object to a PyObject, or how to return it afterwards--i.e. does the boost::python wrapper want me to return a boost::python::object or a PyObject, etc.